# Binomial coefficient (case differentiation)

Tags: binomial-coefficients

If you want to proof $\binom{n}{k}$ + $\binom{n}{k+1}$ = $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$,
you have to differentiate between 5 cases. Why 5 cases and where do they come from ?
It should have something to do with  $\binom{N}{k}$ = $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ .

Comment: "*you have to differentiate between five cases*"  What?  Says who?  "*Why 5 cases and where do they come from?*"  It sounds like you have a particular proof that you want explained.  Share that proof.

Comment: This was a task at my college. You don't have to, but they want this 5 cases; k< -1, k = 1, k = -1 , k = n, k >n, 0<k<n.

Comment: At best guess... I suppose you may be referring to cases such as $k>n>0$, $k=n>0$, $k=n=0$, $k<-1$ and $n<0$ or something... but usually we don't bother with all of these at the time of this proof and just specify that $0\leq k<n$ as a hypothesis.  As for why five cases and not more or less?  That depends entirely on how you choose to organize yourself...

Comment: Exactly, but I don't get it why do I have to do this? What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Why should you restrict yourself to the case where $0\leq k<n$? Because outside of that range you'll have one or all of the terms in your identity equal to zero since they don't correspond to a valid counting question...  Choosing $-3$ objects out of $7$ is impossible, so $\binom{7}{-3}$ is undefined or zero.  Similarly, choosing ten objects out of five is impossible, so $\binom{5}{10}$ is undefined or zero, depending on how you prefer to define it (*zero is more common*).  Why should you pay attention to any case other than the above?  You shouldn't in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, thank u. I've understood the whole situation now.